# Discord.js v12.5.3 Anyone know why this doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

**EDIT:** ColinD solved my problem but now the message doesn't delete and I have no idea why the message wont delete because its worked for me before with bots

Code:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js')
const newEmbed = require('embedcord')
const randomHex = require('random-hex')

module.exports = (client, message, options) => {

let links = require('./links.json')
let foundLink = false
let banReason = (options && options.banReason) || 'Sent a phishing link.'
let logs = (options && options.logs)
let member = message.mentions.members.first()

for(var i in links) {
  if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes(links[i])) foundLink = true
}

if(foundLink) {
  if(message.author.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR'))
    return
  message.delete()
  member.ban({reason: banReason})
  const embed = newEmbed(
    '**Member Banned**',
    `${randomHex.generate()}`,
    `Member was banend for ${options.banReason}`
  )
  logs.send(embed)
}
}
```

Comment: `module.exports = { client, message, options }` perhaps? Or are you trying to declare a function to export? If so, you're missing the arrows, `(client, message, options) => { .... }`. Please provide more details. It's easy to see what's _wrong_ here, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Maybe include the expected way you want this library to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` position might be preventing anything below if from running try changing this

```js
    if (foundLink) {
        if (message.author.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return;
        const embed = newEmbed(
            '**Member Banned**',
            `${randomHex.generate()}`,
            `Member was banend for ${options.banReason}`
        );

        message.delete();
        member.ban({
            reason: banReason
        });
        logs.send(embed);
    }
```

Or this if you want if/else

```js
    if (foundLink) {
        if (message.author.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
            return;
        } else {
            const embed = newEmbed(
                '**Member Banned**',
                `${randomHex.generate()}`,
                `Member was banend for ${options.banReason}`
            );

            message.delete();
            member.ban({
                reason: banReason
            });
            logs.send(embed);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: ColinD solved my problem but now the message doesn't delete and I have no idea why the message wont delete because its worked for me before with bots

`foundLink` variable is unnecessary, you can move your code inside the loop.

Use `message.member.hasPermission()` instead of `message.author.hasPermission()`.

Example code for v12.5.3(Message Event):

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return; // Ignore bot messages

  const { member, channel, guild } = message; // Get the message author, channel, and guild
  if (!member || !channel || !guild) return;  // Ignore messages without a member, channel or guild

  const { links } = require('./links.json');  // Get links from json file

  for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {   // Check if the message contains a link in the links.json file
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(links[i])) {  // If the message contains a link
      if (member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return; // If the member has the administrator permission, don't ban them

      const banReason = 'Sent a phishing link';   // Reason for the ban
      message.delete();  // Delete the message
      guild.member(member).ban({ reason: banReason });   // Ban the member
      channel.send(`${member.displayName} has been banned for sending a phishing link.`)  // Send a message to the channel
      break;
    }
  }
})
```